# Finding lines from a set of points (image processing)

Tags: image-processing

I am not sure this is the right place, but it is a math problem too so let me give it a shot. This problem comes from Robotics but can be totally extricated from there.

In brief, we have a set of points $(x,y)$ on a plane of specific dimension.. (They happen to be points where a sensor has determined there is an obstacle. In reality the obstacles are just straight walls at right angles with each other.)

We want to convert that into a list of lines which are formed by the points. Intuitively if you look at the dots on a screen it's usually quite clear where to draw the lines. Look at this image which as many points. It's sort of obvious where the line segments are (mostly.)

[image]

The algorithm we are using is a Hough transform and we admit that we are not experts in it. We've tweaked the parameters as best we can.

For the input image above it gives us 100-200 lines segments. In "reality" there are maybe 20-30.

Basically this is a function that takes a list of $(x,y)$ pairs and generates a new list of $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$ line segments.

Does anyone have experience with this or refer me somewhere else to look? Thanks!

Pito

Answer (score 1):

With the Hough transform obtained in a python repository we obtain a good result. Here `wmH1C.png` is the furnished picture.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/home/test/Desktop/wmH1C.png')
img.show()
r = img.convert('1')
r.save('/home/test/Desktop/wmH1C.bmp')

image = np.array(Image.open('/home/test/Desktop/wmH1C.bmp'))
(h, theta, d) = hough_line(image)
(fig, axes) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 6), subplot_kw {'adjustable': 'box'})
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Input image')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

ax[1].imshow(np.log(1 + h), extent=[np.rad2deg(theta[-1]), np.rad2deg(theta[0]), d[-1], d[0]],cmap=cm.gray, aspect='auto')#aspect=1/1.5)
ax[1].set_title('Hough transform')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Angles (degrees)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Distance (pixels)')
ax[1].axis('image')

ax[2].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0 = (dist - 0 * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    y1 = (dist - image.shape[1] * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax[2].plot((0, image.shape[1]), (y0, y1), '-r')
ax[2].set_xlim((0, image.shape[1]))
ax[2].set_ylim((image.shape[0], 0))
ax[2].set_axis_off()
ax[2].set_title('Detected lines')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

After processing

[image]